# CheckBox Click event not triggering the function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I am new to JS and Jquery. I am trying to implement a checkbox functionality where the password is shown to the user when the user checks the box .I have browsed through the site and found the answer but it doesn't work for my case.Could somebody point out the mistake I am doing
PS:I am checking whether the function is triggered by the alert event and making the password visible is not yet implemented

```
  <script >

  $("#showpwd").click( function(){
  if( $(this).is(':checked') ){
   alert("Clicked");
   }
  });

  </script>

  <label ><input type="checkbox" id="showpwd "data-mini="true">Show Password</label>
```

Nothing happens when I click on the box

Comment: probably you are getting an error about $ is not defined when the page is loaded, can you check this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LBw9M/)**

Your html is invalid, it should be:

```
<label ><input type="checkbox" id="showpwd" data-mini="true">Show Password</label>
```

and not

```
<label ><input type="checkbox" id="showpwd "data-mini="true">Show Password</label>
                                          ^here
```

- Change the ID attribute. `id="showpwd" data-mini="true"`
- Include jQuery.
- Include the code in `$(document).ready(...)`

Comment: Thank you. @RajaprabhuAravindasamy. Appreciate a comment coming from you.